# Private Chef Supermarket - Is there a way to create DEV and RELEASE spaces for differentiating cookbooks

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

We are thinking about installing a private chef supermarket to host our cookbooks. But trying to find out if there is a way to create separate spaces for DEV and RELEASE cookbooks within the same private Chef Supermarket.

We have 3 different roles in our organisation: Developer, CM and Sys Admin.

We want to have 2 spaces:

1. DEV space
2. RELEASE space.

**DEV space:**

This space is solely for developer. A developer would be sharing his/her cookbooks here. So other developer within the organization can use them. (for e.g., cookbooks for: setting up local environment, necessary things required for development - install_IDE, **installJDK**, etc). However CM and Sys Admins should not have access nor see the cookbooks uploaded by the developers.

**RELEASE space:**

In the release space, only CM would be uploading/sharing cookbooks in this space. (for e.g., installApp1Prod, installApp2Prod, **installJDK**, etc ) System Admins should have only read access/download access to the cookbooks.

**Note** - CM can share a cookbook of the same name as developers (for e.g, **installJDK**) but Sys Admins should only see the one shared by CM.

Please let me know if this is even possible do in the Chef Private Supermarket or do I need to install 2 separate private Supermarkets for DEV and RELEASE spaces. If I have to install 2 separate Supermarkets how do I manage the permissions from 1 chef server?

Please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Supermarket app only supports a single namespace. Take a look at Artifactory's cookbook repo support though, it could do what you want. Or use two Supermarkets as you noted. Permissions are managed entirely within Supermarket so you can't do that centrally.